# How to solve FATAL EXCEPTION java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()

Tags: android, synchronization, fatal-error

i am developing chat related similar application i am using backgrouund synchronous class some times force close is appear i am using .net webservices back ground i am recieve the messages and images background download process updating to ui

error is:

```
05-17 05:24:17.925: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1618): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
05-17 05:24:17.925: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1618): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
05-17 05:24:17.925: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1618):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
05-17 05:24:17.925: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1618):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
05-17 05:24:17.925: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1618):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
05-17 05:24:17.925: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1618):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
05-17 05:24:17.925: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1618):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
05-17 05:24:17.925: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1618):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
05-17 05:24:17.925: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1618):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
05-17 05:24:17.925: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1618):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
05-17 05:24:17.925: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1618): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
05-17 05:24:17.925: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1618):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:257)
05-17 05:24:17.925: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1618):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:311)
05-17 05:24:17.925: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1618):     at com.fitzgeraldsoftware.shout.presentationLayer.Shout$LatestMessage.doInBackground(Shout.java:1923)
05-17 05:24:17.925: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1618):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
05-17 05:24:17.925: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1618):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
05-17 05:24:17.925: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1618):     ... 4 more
05-17 05:24:17.956: WARN/ActivityManager(1105):   Force finishing activity com.fitzgeraldsoftware.shout.presentationLayer/.Shout
05-17 05:24:18.097: WARN/IInputConnectionWrapper(1618): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
```

Comment: Post ur error Prone code

Comment: What does the code look like around line 1923 in Shout.java?

Comment: i got it thank u for valuable response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` thrown. Check the code executed on 1923 in `Shout.java` for array access. The exception is thrown if you try to read element by index which is more than array size(1). For example it is thrown if:

```
String [] strings = new String[0];
strings[0];// exception thrown!
```

Answer (score 3):

I face the same problem and almost i sepnt half day on it, Finally the solution was Shut down you eclipse and PC/Laptop, Restart it and run the Application. Everything is running fine.

Comment: hi pakshaheen u can synroniazed threads this problem is solved i am asynroniazation some ui hanged this time error is occured u can use synroniazed threads its run one after one this is better way

Answer (score 1):

Try `Project -> Clean` and then Run.... I have Solved it this way.......